# Website Scoping For Products in Admin

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, multistore, products-management, websites

I want to manage the products in magento on a website scope instead of the default scope. The problem is, that i am not allowed to access the website/store-scope because its greyed out / disabled.
However, i can alter them on a view scope level, but since i can have multiple views, this would be a heavy workload to alter the attributes for every view instead of website/store level.

Is there a solution, that a developer can somehow override this default behavior of the catalog/products adminhtml?

[image: Scopes]
In the picture i want to set values for the according Testsite/Teststore scope which is currently denied for me.

I also want to achieve the same behavior for third party extensions which operate on the same way (not within System -> Configuration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible. The EAV attribute values can only be stored per **store** or globally, there is no scope type similar to the system configuration.

#### Example:

```
mysql> show columns from catalog_product_entity_int;
+----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| value_id       | int(11)              | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| entity_type_id | int(10) unsigned     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| attribute_id   | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| store_id       | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| entity_id      | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value          | int(11)              | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Attributes that have a "website" scope such as the price, actually store their values for the default store of the current website.

Comment: ah..I was a few seconds too late.

Comment: yep, that was close :)

Comment: In my screenshot above i could not edit on the store level, only within default and per store-view. Do i miss something?

Comment: Yes, Magento uses different vocabulary internally (website, store_group, store) and in the user interface (Website, Store, Store View), just to mess with us. And I am speaking the internal language

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit products ad website scope because there is no website scope for products.
Product attribute values are kept relative to store view id (adn 0 for the global values).
But you can change some attributes scope to website and when you edit their values for one store view they will be changed for all store views under the same website.

Comment: In other words changing one view is the same as changing on store level? But what happens if i change multiple views for one store? And in my screenshot abouve, i could not edit on **website** level